# Is there a way to filter rows in a dynamic pivot stored procedure?

Tags: sql, filter, pivot, where-clause, procedure

I can filter columns but not rows.

Here is my iGuide Table data I use with my PIVOT:

---

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Zone    Enabled     Channel  DMA    Region    HQ       Machine
ACC         1        AEN    Norfolk  Other   virginia   dzsfk
ACC         1        CNN    Norfolk  Other   virginia   dzsfk
ACC         1        ESPN   Norfolk  Other   virginia   dzsfk
ACC         1        HIST   Norfolk  Other   virginia   dzsfk
ACC         1        FOOD   Norfolk  Other   virginia   dzsfk
ANJ         1        AEN    Paducah  Pacific hqs3ftbgwi adanj
ANJ         1        ESPN   Paducah  Pacific hqs3ftbgwi adanj
ANJ         1        HIST   Paducah  Pacific hqs3ftbgwi adanj
ANJ         1        CNN    Paducah  Pacific hqs3ftbgwi adanj
CHD         1        ESPN   Denver   Pacific hqs3ftbgwi adchd
CHD         1        FOOD   Denver   Pacific hqs3ftbgwi adchd
CHD         1        DISC   Denver   Pacific hqs3ftbgwi adchd
CHI         1        AEN    Denver   Pacific hqs3ftbgwi adchd
CHI         1        FOOD   Chico    Pacific hqs4ftbgwi adv1chicca
CHI         1        ESPN   Chico    Pacific hqs4ftbgwi adv1chicca
CHI         1        CNN    Chico    Pacific hqs4ftbgwi adv1chicca

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is an example of my initial result of Stored Procedure without any filters:
```

---

```
CHANNEL | ACC | ANJ | CHD | CHI |
AEN        1     1    NULL   1
CNN        1     1    NULL   1
ESPN       1     1     1     1  
FOOD       1    NULL   1     1
HIST       1     1    NULL  NULL
DISC     NULL   NULL   1    NULL
_________________________________________________
```

HERE is my current result I get after applying a zone @Filter = 'ACC':

```
_________________________________________________
CHANNEL | ACC |
AEN        1  
CNN        1
ESPN       1
FOOD       1
HIST       1
DISC      NULL
_________________________________________________
```

My desired result is to get this:

```
_________________________________________________
CHANNEL | ACC |
AEN        1  
CNN        1
ESPN       1
FOOD       1
HIST       1
_________________________________________________
```

How do I get rid of empty NULL rows when applying my filter?

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
    USE [Media_Ops]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Usp_GetWHERE]
    @Filter Varchar(MAX)

    AS

   DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)      
           ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @columns = N''
    --Get column names for entire pivoting
    SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(Zone)
      FROM (select distinct Zone 
            from iGuide  WHERE (DMA LIKE @Filter)   OR (Channel = @Filter) OR (@Filter = ' Select All') OR (@Filter = 'Select All') OR (Zone LIKE @Filter) OR (Machine LIKE @Filter) OR (Company LIKE @Filter) OR (HQ LIKE @Filter) OR (Region LIKE @Filter)
         ) AS T
    --select @columns
    SET @sql = N'
    SELECT  Distinct Channel, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
    FROM iGuide 
    PIVOT
    (
      count(Zone) FOR Zone IN ('
      + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
      + ')
    ) AS Pivot1  ORDER BY Channel
    ' 
    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: what is your current result with that query?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am getting an output of everything in ACC column. I don't want to see rows with NULLs. 
_____________

Comment: And what is your source data? To me looks like you should filter before send to pivot

Comment: Hey Juan, I use Sql Server Database as a data source.

Comment: I mean show us sample data, you only show us the result

Comment: I use a table with 8 different columns: Channel, Zone, Machine, HQ, DMA, Company, Enabled, Region. My table has 20000 rows of data. Let me show you some of the output I get when I load the table without any filters.

Comment: Also you can prepare a working sample in rextester.com. That allow us to do some testing

Comment: Zone Enabled Channel DMA Region HQ Machine
ACC 1 AEN Norfolk-Portsmth-Newpt Nws Other virginia dzsfk
ACC 1 CNN Norfolk-Portsmth-Newpt Nws Other virginia dzsfk
ACC 1 ESPN Norfolk-Portsmth-Newpt Nws Other virginia dzsfk

Comment: dont post data in comment, just edit your question

Comment: I just  updated the question. Look at the very top of it and you will see my iGuide table that feeds the pivot and stored procedure. Thanks for your help Juan!

Comment: this sample doesnt produce same result as you question: http://rextester.com/MDPWLQ71158, please update and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/NBL79508)**
Create a new variable `@zone` to filter before pivot

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[Usp_GetWHERE]
    @Filter Varchar(MAX)

AS

   DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)      
           ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
           ,@zone NVARCHAR(MAX)

    --Get column names for entire pivoting
    SET @columns = N''
    SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(Zone)
      FROM (select distinct Zone 
            from iGuide  WHERE (DMA LIKE @Filter)   OR (Channel = @Filter) OR (@Filter = ' Select All') OR (@Filter = 'Select All') OR (Zone LIKE @Filter) OR (Machine LIKE @Filter) OR (HQ LIKE @Filter) OR (Region LIKE @Filter)
         ) AS T

    --Get column names for filter source    
    SET @zone = N''
    SELECT @zone += N', ' + QUOTENAME(Zone, '''')
      FROM (select distinct Zone 
            from iGuide  WHERE (DMA LIKE @Filter)   OR (Channel = @Filter) OR (@Filter = ' Select All') OR (@Filter = 'Select All') OR (Zone LIKE @Filter) OR (Machine LIKE @Filter) OR (HQ LIKE @Filter) OR (Region LIKE @Filter)
         ) AS T

    SET @zone = '(' + substring(@zone, 3, len(@zone)-2) + ')';         

    SET @sql = N'
    SELECT  [Channel], ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
    FROM (SELECT Channel, [Zone]
          FROM iGuide 
          WHERE [Zone] IN ' + @zone + ')  as source
    PIVOT
    (
      count([Zone]) FOR [Zone] IN ('
      + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
      + ')
    ) AS Pivot1  ORDER BY Channel
    ' 
    select @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

GO 
EXECUTE [dbo].Usp_GetWHERE N'ACC';
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Juan, it worked perfectly! However when I am trying to apply the rest of the filters, I get an error : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: I was trying to input "Norfolk" and got that error message

Comment: well `Norfolk` is `DMA` not `[Zone]` You need expand the cases.

Comment: My mistake, the problem is with empty string let me give a second look.

Comment: In my side `Norfolk` doesnt give me error. http://rextester.com/URDKYV32232

Comment: Juan, I have some of the zones that are 10 characters long, is that going to be a problem?

Comment: Not sure, change `[Region] varchar(7)` to a bigger number, but in my side only get error if you filter doesnt return result. But if you update the rextestet with additional data maybe I can reproduce the error.

Comment: let me do that real quick

Comment: Juan, I just updated the Rextester.com HERE IS THE LInk http://rextester.com/ZVXJD56249

Comment: I have added some values to the table. I really appreciate all your help! Please let me know if you need anything!

Comment: Yes, the link to new test :P. ... press save/fork and send me new link

Comment: Sorry only saw the last comment not the previous last :P

Comment: I didn't attach it first, but then figured you would need it))

Comment: what is the problem? beside you miss the close parenthesis on the create table

Comment: did you try to run the query? If it worked please send me a link so I can try it on my end

Comment: I am trying to populate my gridview using drop down list and getting " Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: well that is a different problem, sql demo work ok, isnt?

Comment: Demo worked, however the stored procedure in the gridview keeps giving Invalid length parameter passed to the Left or Substring function.

Comment: Again that is a different problem. I suggest you create a small storeproc and try to isolate the issue, and maybe ask in a different question. But this question is solved.

Comment: Definitely! You have no idea how much I appreciate your help, Juan! You made my day!

Comment: Juan, one last thing. Do you know how to get rid of all select statements and only display the actual result table? I see 4 pivoted tables with no data when I execute the stored procedure. The table with results is located at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: yes, just comment all previous `select @variable`, I include it to make clear what was happen, but arent necesary.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks a Lot  for your help!

Comment: Juan, I have a question. When I am trying to search for AEN channel in the stored procedure, it outputs other channels too. Is there a way to only output AEN channel? Here is the link for the rextester site: http://rextester.com/URDKYV32232

Comment: Your test look for `ACC` not `AEN`

Comment: Please, Try AEN when you search.

Comment: dont know what you mean.

Comment: I have updated my query. Everything works now. If you are still interested what I meant, try to search for 'AEN' and you should be able to get only 1 line.